# Group by after particular condition matched

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider my table `transactions` below

```
+----+---------+-------+--------+
| id | user_id | value | tag    |
+----+---------+-------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |    30 | ''     |
|  2 |       1 |    20 | 'foo'  |
|  3 |       1 |   -10 | ''     |
|  4 |       2 |    60 | ''     |
|  5 |       2 |    30 | 'foo'  |
|  6 |       2 |   -25 | ''     |
+----+---------+-------+--------+
```

I want to group by `user_id`, to get the `sum(value)`, for rows after a tag is matched "**foo**" (which the rows of their `id` is greater than the matched row)

for example, the above table, I want to get the following

```
+---------+-------+
| user_id | value |
+---------+-------+
|       1 |    10 |
|       2 |     5 |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: and you should aware of that you have to first try something and then come here if you get some error as you are old user here

Comment: As a general group by tip - Selected columns that are not argument to set-functions should be listed in the group by clause.

Answer (score 3):

You could use self join:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, SUM(t2.`value`) AS `value`
FROM transactions t1
JOIN transactions t2
  ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
 AND t1.id <= t2.id
WHERE t1.tag = 'foo'
GROUP BY t1.user_id;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/427395)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════╗
║ user_id ║ value ║
╠═════════╬═══════╣
║       1 ║    10 ║
║       2 ║     5 ║
╚═════════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, sum(value)
from transactions as t1
where id >=
   ( select min(id)  -- find the 1st 'foo' id for each user
     from transactions as t2
     where tag = 'foo'
       and t1.user_id = t2.user_id
   )
group by user_id
```